# Using QT 4.7 - dialog is busy loading a BIG thing; how to disable all controls?

Tags: qt, dialog

**[EDIT] - wasn't getting to the disable code the way I thought I was; works fine with any of the solutions below.**

I have a modeless QT dialog, in which all kinds of user settings can be manipulated. In addition, it can save and load large data sets, which can take several seconds. Lots going on in the main window underneath (realtime app) and that's fine, and interaction there is okay, but in the dialog itself, I need to block user interaction.

Essentially, during the load, I don't want the user to be able to change / affect any of the controls in the modeless dialog (and there are a lot of them.)

Rather than disable each one individually (or even that way if that's the only way), is there a straightforward means I can use to disable input to the dialog entirely until the load is complete?

There's a progress bar in it that shows what's going on, too, which is constantly updated by the load process, so that needs to keep on working.

I tried this...

On dialog open:

```
QDialog *window = this;
```

Then around load:

```
window->setDisabled(true);
....
window->setDisabled(false);
```

...which compiles fine, and runs without complaint, but the window did not disable.

I also tried:

```
window->setEnabled(false);
....
window->setEnabled(true);
```

...that doesn't seem to do anything either.

I tried this too:

```
QList<QWidget*> list = window->findChildren<QWidget *>();
foreach(QWidget *qw, list)
{
    qw->setEnabled(false);
}
....
QList<QWidget*> list = window->findChildren<QWidget *>();
foreach(QWidget *qw, list)
{
    qw->setEnabled(true);
}
```

..also does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Qt documentation (http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enabled-prop):

> Disabling a widget implicitly disables all its children. Enabling
>   respectively enables all child widgets unless they have been
>   explicitly disabled.

So your snippets are essentially doing same thing in different ways so that doesn't seem to be a problem and modality of dialog shouldn't have any effect on this as well. How are you loading / saving the data? If you are doing it in e.g. click slot then you are basically blocking the UI event loop which means that UI doesn't have cycles to react to your changes. If you want to isolate UI from background action so it will properly react even that you are doing heavy lifting in the background and you should consider using `QRunnable` or `QTread` to offload the work away from UI thread.

Comment: The dialog and the mainwindow remain completely live during the load process. You can enter data, click widgets, the dialog responds normally during the load. It's getting all the usual IO. I don't want it to, though.

Comment: What kind of controls are in the dialog? Are you creating it using Qt Forms Designer or are you building it in code? By the way, why are you doing this?
     QDialog *window = this;

Comment: There are various controls; form designer built it. Text entry controls, checkboxes, radio buttons inside a groupbox. I am doing that so that the class has a variable handy set to the instance of the qdialog. I wasn't sure what "this" meant in the context of someone having clicked the load button; was it the dialog, or the button? Since it didn't work to disable anything, I figured it might not have been the dialog, so I did that when the dialog was instantiated. But it made no difference anyway.

Comment: okay, got it working. Wasn't actually getting to the calls, sigh. Thank you.